# How can I export data to excel using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and keep the data format.

Tags: c#, excel

Sample code is

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=E:\Application\PASpready\Files\NK\NKAll.xlsx;HDR=YES;','SELECT * FROM [All$]') 
select ..... from table
```

All the data comes over as text and number decimals loose their format. How can i keep the data format in excel.

Comment: ACE, AFAIK infers the types based on the actual data. How many rows are you exporting? Do the values within one column have a mix of different types or are they uniform?

Comment: am exporting 40,000+ records data type in columns are the same.  am working with uniform data. i am using sql 2005.  thanks much...

Comment: You could try building that NKAll.xlsx file prior to exporting, as a template. With a dummy row of data with correct formats. That might help excel infer the types correctly. If that works, then you can first update the first row, and then insert all the rest.

Comment: thanks much...
i create the excel sheet dynamically.  i wrote a fake starting cell and that works.
creating a dummy row works great.

Comment: Excellent, would you like me to post that comment as an answer so that you can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building that *NKAll.xlsx* file prior to exporting, as a template, having a dummy row of data with correct formats.

That might help excel infer the types correctly. If that works, then you can initially update the first row, and then insert all the rest.

Comment: It did work 7 years ago when I answered the question, which is why the answer was accepted! Learn to be respectful to others. If the answer no longer works (since it has been almost a decade), find a more up to date way of getting it working, and post it with an appropriate comment to help others.

Comment: Yes, for 7 years things can change. Sorry about bad voting, I think I fix it on some of your other answers. Thank you for your contribution to Dev community!